# Why aren't apps created with the Office 365 App Registration Tool visible in the Azure Management Portal?

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I successfully registered an app using the Office 365 App Registration Tool:

https://dev.office.com/app-registration

The tool says "Once you register an app here, you can manage your registration using the Azure Management Portal". However, when I go to the Azure Management Portal:

http://manage.windowsazure.com/

I don't see the application listed in the Applications section. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I can see mine no problem, sorry to ask a stupid question but you are looking under Active Directory and selecting the appropriate directory if you have more than one?

Comment: Yep, I go to Active Directory -> <Name> -> Applications to pull up the list of applications. Only the applications that I created within manage.windowsazure.com (and others outside of this process) show up. Not those that I created on dev.office.com.

Comment: What role are you in the directory? Are you a global administrator? Should see this on the Active Directory pane it will tell you next to the directory name

Comment: Yes I'm a Global Administrator.

Comment: What happens if you try searching, do they come up then or not visible at all? Also try the ARM portal as well (portal.azure.com)

Comment: Have you looked in the current portal? (portal.azure.com)

Comment: 1) The application doesn't show up when I search.
2) I don't even see my active directory listed in portal.azure.com, for the same reasons I suspect as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062647/azure-ad-for-office-365-does-not-show-in-new-portal

Comment: Ah, just found the answer! Will post it as a response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Applications section, select `Applications my company owns` in the `Show` option menu -- which is *not* necessarily a subset of the default `Applications my company uses` -- then click the search button. This shows the applications created with the Office 365 App Registration Tool.

Comment: That was the next question :)